# Decrypt BIP38 encryption?

Tags: command-line, security, encryption

On [Walletgenerator](https://walletgenerator.net) the private keys of paper wallets can be encrypted and decrypted using BIP38. How can that be done using Ubuntu and a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the JavaScript component **bip38** you can install with `npm`:

```
npm install --save bip38
```

It comes with simple methods to encrypt and decrypt private keys, see [its Github page](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip38#api) for the syntax and further reading.

If you want to learn how to use JavaScript in shell scripts I recommend this article: [How to Write Shell Scripts with JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/shell-scripts-javascript/)